How to decode string to Unicode code points?
I got string that can contain any Unicode characters:
ABC 

(4th character is SPACE)
I want:
U+0041 U+0042 U+0043 U+0020

How to do this?

use the codePoints() method of String (javadoc) to get the code points and then format() or formatted(), also of String, to format the code points ( e.g. "ABC ".codePoints().mapToObj("U+%04x"::formatted).collect(Collectors.joining(" ")) )

Do you want the characters 'U' '+'  '0' '0' '4' '1' ' ' ... ?

@user85421 that's compelling, but try that with ABC followed by the UK flag (U+1F1EC U+1F1E7) which is one grapheme

Why is this closed? What more “details or clarity” do you want?

@g00se what's the problem? ("ABC" + Character.toString(0x1F1EC) + Character.toString(0x1F1E7)).codePoints().mapToObj("U+%04x"::formatted).collect(Collectors.joining(" ")) ==> "U+0041 U+0042 U+0043 U+1f1ec U+1f1e7"  OP is not asking for grapheme

@user85421 Look up terms on Wikipedia such as code point, grapheme, glyph. What looks like one character to the human reader can actually be a composition of multiple code points. For example, a letter with one or more diacriticals, or an emoji depicting human body part in natural skin tone. So you can have more code points than apparent characters.

@user85421 I mistook you for the OP.

IntStream of code points
As commented, you should work through the stream of code point integer numbers returned by String#codePoints.
int[] codePoints = "ABC ".codePoints().toArray() ;

Define a format string for your desired output with hexadecimal numbers.
"U+%04x"

Loop though those code point int values, generating text for each.
for ( int codePoint : codePoints ) 
{
    String result = String.format( "U+%04x" , codePoint ) ;
    System.out.println( result ) ;
}

You can gather those outputs with StringBuilder.
Or put that all together in a one-liner:
String results = 
    "ABC "
    .codePoints()
    .mapToObj( ( int i ) -> String.format( "U+%04x" , i )  )
    .collect( java.util.stream.Collectors.joining( " " ) )
;

See this code run at Ideone.com.

U+0041 U+0042 U+0043 U+0020


Be aware that text is a complicated matter.
What looks like one character to the human reader can actually be a composition of multiple code points. For example, a letter with one or more diacriticals. Another example is an emoji depicting human body part in natural skin tone. So you can have more code points than apparent characters.
To learn more, look up terms on Wikipedia such as code point, grapheme, glyph, diacritical, ligature.

In Java, you can achieve this by iterating over each character in the string, converting it to its Unicode code point using the Character.codePointAt() method, and then formatting it as desired.
public class UnicodeDecoder {
    public static String decodeToUnicodeCodePoints(String input) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            int codePoint = input.codePointAt(i);
            builder.append(String.format("U+%04X ", codePoint));
            // Move index to the next character if the current character is part of a surrogate pair
            if (Character.isHighSurrogate(input.charAt(i))) {
                i++;
            }
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "ABC ";
        String decodedString = decodeToUnicodeCodePoints(input);
        System.out.println(decodedString);
    }
}


maybe better use offsetByCodePoints() to directly calculate the index, instead of isHighSurrogate(), and loop up to codePointCount()  -- BTW StringBuilder + format() == Formatter - see javadoc

Incorrect. String#length is based on outmoded char type rather than code points. So it can return a wrong number for most characters. And length will not necessarily agree with codePointAt. Avoid char as it has been essentially broken since Java 2, legacy since Java 5.

@Basil isn't that solved by using isHighSurrogate() and additional increment of i in posted code? It is working correctly for the UK flag example given in the comment to the question (I would prefer other solutions)

The code is correct. Still, the only thing this code is useful for is as a how-not-to-do-it example.

Because the code iterates over chars, then does some magic so that there is only one iteration per codepoint - instead of iterating over codepoints in the first place.

Did you create this answer with ChatGPT?
